# Is is possible to use other files as a map instead of the Google Apis Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

Instead of using the Google Apis Map from the MapView android tutorial, can I use other files such as a photo or a picture to substitute as a map?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#CustomMapTypes